# passing values to a dropdownlist in an mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, viewdata

I am a newb to MVC programming.  I am passing values from other db tables to my edit and create views to populate some dropdownlists.  It's working great.  I have code like this in my controller for edit and create:

```
var db = new MyProgramDataContext();
Order order = orderRepository.GetOrder(id);
ViewData["customer"] = from c in db.customers
                       select new SelectListItem
                       {
                              Text = c.customer_name,
                              Value = c.customer_name
                       }
return View(order);
```

I want to move the select statement to the Respository to make things a bit cleaner so that I'm not repeating the same selects in Edit and Create.

```
ViewData["customer"] = orderRepository.GetCustomers();
```

In the `Repository`, should the return type of `GetCustomers` be `SelectListItem`?  I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You probably ought to tag this with the framework and language in which you are doing this MVC programming. MVC is a pattern that has been implemented on a great times in a great many ways.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was my first tag, but it's not there...  Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have my SelectLists in a FormViewModel class and am using partial views for my edit and create code.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Check out how Rob Conery has implemented it on his blog:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-and-html-attributes/

You can get all the customers, and then create a SelectList and set your ViewData accordingly.

Comment: OK, so I'm now returning the data from Respository as IQueryable and then in the Controller doing:
ViewData["customer"] = new SelectList(orderRespository.GetCustomers(), "customer_name", "customer_name", order.customer);

That's working.  Is it the best way?

Comment: If it works, continue using it. You can always return to this code in the future if/when you find a better implementation that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way

move such kind of function on some helper class like DDLHelper

```
<select id="idXYZ" name="XYZ">
  <%= DDLHelper.DDl_order(Model.orderId)%>
</select>
```

Write your function in some helper class like DDLHelper

```
    public static string DDl_order(int orderId)
        {
            string format = "<option value=\"{0}\" {2} >{1}</option>";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat(format, "", "--Select--", "");

            List<Models.UrClass> urclass=orderRepository.GetCustomers();

            foreach (var item in client)
            {
                string ordid = item.orderId.ToString().Encrypt();

                if (item.ClientID == orderId)
                    sb.AppendFormat(format, orderid , item.OrdName,selected=\"selected\"");
                else
                    sb.AppendFormat(format, ordid , item.OrdName, "");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```